# Corda: InstantiationException when extending FungibleState in custom Schema

Tags: jpa, kotlin, corda

This issue is similar to the one posted here: [Corda: error=org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475265/corda-error-org-hibernate-instantiationexception-no-default-constructor-for-en)

I am getting the same error for a custom schema extending FungibleState (as described in the [API Vault Query documentation](https://docs.corda.net/head/api-vault-query.html)):

```
object CustomSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(schemaFamily = CustomSchema.javaClass, version = 1, mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentCustomState::class.java))
{
@Entity
@Table(name = "custom_states", indexes = arrayOf(Index(name = "custom_field_idx", columnList = "custom_field")))
class PersistentCustomState(

    /** Custom attributes */
    @Column(name = "custom_field")
    var customField: String? = null,

    /** FungibleState parent attributes */
    @Transient
    val _participants: Set<AbstractParty>,
    @Transient
    val _owner: AbstractParty,
    @Transient
    val _quantity: Long,
    @Transient
    val _issuerParty: AbstractParty,
    @Transient
    val _issuerRef: OpaqueBytes
) : CommonSchemaV1.FungibleState(_participants?.toMutableSet(), _owner, _quantity, _issuerParty, _issuerRef.bytes)}
```

Example schema found here: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/finance/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/finance/schemas/SampleCashSchemaV2.kt

I have the `kotlin-jpa` plugin installed. Making all fields nullable seems to solve the issue for schemas extending `PersistentState`, but is not an option here because of the `FungibleState` parent field data types.

Corda release version = 2.0.0

Comment: Have you tried creating a default constructor with no args, that passes empty strings, zeros, etc. to the parent constructor. Something like: `constructor() : this("", "", "", "")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a default constructor to the body of `PersistentCustomState`. Something like:

```
constructor() : this(*first default value*, *second default value*, etc.)
```

The difficulty will be in passing default values for the `AbstractParty` parameters. You can use something like:

```
AnonymousParty(generateKeyPair().public)
```

Comment: Adding a default constructor works for now. I still consider this a workaround though, I would think that the `kotlin-jpa` plugin would handle this for me (and without the need to be able to make all fields nullable)